# How to remove the attached file in input file? (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, attachment

How to remove the selected attachment from `<input type="file">` element ?
Firefox doesn't seem to be able to remove the attachment when you already have one selected.

I tried to delete the name and click open but nothing happened.
I also tried to cancel but the attachment is still there.

My solution would be to add some onclick javascript to remove the value but is there a way not to add some script just like in the attachment of chrome?

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

No, I think you will have to insert some js.

It appears that Firefox keeps the value of file inputs into cache, ( like any other input value btw ) and only updates it if a new value is added.

The cancel button doesn't clear it, which makes sense in my understanding of english because if I want to "cancel" the action of selecting an other file, it doesn't mean I want to "clear" the one I had before.

If you really want your users to be able to clear those, you could add some button to do it

```js
var f = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]'),
clearInput = function(){this.previousSibling.value = '';};
for(var i = 0; i < f.length; i++){
  button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = 'clear';
  button.addEventListener('click', clearInput);
  f[i].parentNode.insertBefore(button, f[i].nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<input type="file"/><br>
<input type="file"/><br>
<input type="file"/><br>
```

or clear it each time he searches for a new file.

```js
var f = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]');
var clearInput = function(){this.value=''};
for(var i=0;i<f.length; i++)
  f[i].addEventListener('click', clearInput);
```

```html
<input type="file"/><br>
<input type="file"/><br>
<input type="file"/><br>
```

Comment: yeah the cancel button is a bit confusing, because if youre using chrome often when you hit the cancel button or close button it will automaticaly remove the selected file. BTW thanks for the answer. Voting this as a correct answer because YOU ARE RIGHT and you are the only one answers my question.